# ASP.NET CORE SignInAsync Requires Browser Refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am building an intranet site that uses Windows Authentication, but stores authorization claims using Entity Framework.  There is no user log-in.  If the browser is closed (cookie deleted) and the application re-started (CNTRL F5), Home/Index controller checks that the users WindowsIdentity is registered, and is supposed to sign in the user.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        string userWin = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userWin);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            string userHTTP = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
            ViewData["Message"] = $"Registered User: {user} and HTTPUser: {userHTTP} is registered for this site";
        }
        else
            ViewData["Message"] = "Please contact admin to register for this website";

        return View();
    }
```

The first time this is run, userHTTP is null and view html requiring user sign-in does not execute.  If the browser is refreshed, then everything is OK.  Why does the sign in and HTTPContext require a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is "by design".  From the docs: *ASP.NET Core provides cookie middleware which serializes a user principal into an encrypted cookie and then, on subsequent requests, validates the cookie, recreates the principal and assigns it to the User property on HttpContext*. 
Since this is an intranet site with Windows Authentication, site registered users get a signed in user view without a login redirect. The Index function was redirected to itself to simulate a subsequent request:

```
            string userHTTP = User.Identity.Name;
            if (userHTTP == null)
            { //will be null on first request with new cookie.  Rerun the request.
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            }
            else
                ViewData["Message"] = $"Registered User: {user} and HTTPUser: {userHTTP} is registered for this site";
```

I am new to all this. If unadvised, please add comment.